# Difficulty on passing a variable along with event

Tags: c#

I need to pass the value for `maxColumns` to a method that will be used repeatedly by other items.  How can I go about passing `maxColumns` in this scenario?

```
public partial class ValResults : Form
{
    public ValResults()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Table1Requirements();

    }

    private void Table1Requirements()
    {
        int maxColumns = 6;
        this.table1LayoutPanelPrime.CellPaint += new TableLayoutCellPaintEventHandler(tableLayoutPaint);

    }

   void tableLayoutPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxColumns; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row == 0 && e.Column == i)
            {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass is to what?  I recommend you read up on variable scope in C#, as well as methods and arguments.  As it stands now, your posted code, your loop won't run because `maxColumns` will be 0 (default value).

Comment: There will be a total of 5 tables all requiring that the same header is highlighted.  Rather than just copy pasting code I was hoping to just use the same loop.  Right now I have the loop hard coded to 7 however this won't work for the next sections.

Alex, yep that is what I am trying to do.  If I can't do it I can't do it, just reaching out to see if it is possible.

Comment: the loop is not needed. Just `if (e.Row == 0 && e.Column < maxColumns)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can essentially pre build a function using lambdas...

```
private void Table1Requirements()
    {
        int maxColumns = 6;
        this.table1LayoutPanelPrime.CellPaint += new TableLayoutCellPaintEventHandler(tableLayoutPaint(maxColumns));

    }

   Action<object,TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs> tableLayoutPaint(int columns)
    return (sender, e) => 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row == 0 && e.Column == i)
            {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, r);
            }
        }
    }
```

that way you can generate different event handles with different max column settings

Answer (score 1):

If its in the same class, just define the variable at the class level.

```
 private int _maxColumns;
 public ValResults()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Table1Requirements();
        SetColumnCount(); 
    }

private void SetColumnCount(){
    _maxColumns= 6;
}

void tableLayoutPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _maxColumns; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row == 0 && e.Column == i)
        {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, r);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: think you missed the bit that they want to reuse the handler in different scenarios with different maxColumns